# Ten Rebus puzzles

Tags: rebus

Solve the following ten one-line Rebus puzzles:

1. DICTNARY
2. PRAHOMTE
3. ..AVI..
4. MARY+MARY+MARY
5. /r/e/a/d/i/n/g/
6. MTWTFSSS
7. 144 144 word word word word
8. LIFE = TTTT--------->
9. WORLD WORLD WORLD WORLD
10. SUGAR x SUGAR x SUGAR

Comment: Not sure how they qualify as Rebus puzzles... (unless I have another definition in mind of what they are)
I can't figure them all out, and on some I'm not entirely sure if my guess is correct.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answers (joint work by aes, dmg, Engineer Toast, Gamow,Hellion):

1:

> DICTNARY = shortened DICTIONARY = **abridged dictionary**

2:

> PRAHOMTE = METAPHOR scrambled and mixed = **Mixed metaphor**

3:

> ..AVI.. = center piece of GRAVITY = **The center of gravity**

4:

> MARY+MARY+MARY = SUM of MARY = **Summary**

5:

> /r/e/a/d/i/n/g/ = **reading between the lines**

6:

> MTWTFSSS = initial letters of weekdays + an extra saturday/sunday = **Eight days a week**
>  or: **Long weekend**
>  or: **Every day of the week and twice on Sundays**

7:

> 144 144 word word word word = 2 gross, 4 words = **too gross for words**

8:

> LIFE = TTTT---------> = Life is something that begins at 4T = **Life begins at forty**

9:

> WORLD WORLD WORLD WORLD = **World Series**

10:

> SUGAR x SUGAR x SUGAR = **sugar cube**

Comment: To help out, what I thought:
8 = life begins at forty

Comment: prahomte = metaphor?

Comment: I *think* #1 is "abridged dictionary", but won't add unless confirmed.

Comment: Could #1 be Closed Dictionary, since the middle isn't "opened" for us to see?

Comment: Since what's missing from "DICTIONARY" is "IO", maybe it's an "unspoken rule". "Unspoken" plays off I/O being input/output and "rule" playing off the dictionary as a rule for spelling words.

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

2.

> mixed metaphor

6.

> long weekend (three S in the sequence MTWTFSSS)

9.

> FOUR WORLD -> Forward or Foreword

Answer (score 2):

One more guess for #6:

> Eight days a week.

What can I say, I love the Beatles.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative possible answer for 6:

> And twice on Sundays. (Or perhaps the full phrase: Every day of the week and twice on Sundays.)

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer:

1.

> DICTNARY = DICTIONARY - "IO" = either end of the dictionary = Bookends

Comment: Actually, it should be `DICTIONARY - "IO"`

Comment: @MatiCicero See, I would have caught that if I hadn't been going so quickly... Thanks for pointing it out.